# Cyclic inequality for $n$ numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a,b,c,x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n>0, a+b+c=1,\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n x_i=1 $ . Prove that $$(ax_1^2+bx_1+c)...(ax_n^2+bx_n+c)\geq1$$.

I've tried just writing out as a product using the product sign and then to group certain parts of the product. Nothing came out puf it what we need. Also tried induction with the base $n=1,2$ rather straightforward. How is it done?

Comment: If $a = b = c = \frac{1}{4}$ and $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n = 1$, then the left side is $(3/4)^n$ which is less than $1$. Are you sure you aren't missing any conditions on $a,b,c$?

Comment: are you sure this is right? let $a=b=c=x_{i}=\dfrac{1}{1000}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=1,a+b+c=1$$

then Use [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)
$$(ax^2_{1}+bx_{1}+c)(ax^2_{2}+bx_{2}+c)\cdots (ax^2_{n}+bx_{n}+c)\ge \\(a(x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n})^{\frac{2}{n}}+b(x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}+c)^n=(a+b+c)^n=1$$

Comment: @r9m Absolutely. I need to get hold at Holder's. Thanks!

Comment: @JackiePoehler yes ! see his solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039510/inequality-a33b25b33c25c33a25-ge-27abc3) for example ! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Notice $a, b, c > 0$ and $a + b + c = 1$. By AM $\ge$ GM, we have

$$a x_i^2 + b x_i + c \ge (x_i^2)^a (x_i)^b 1^c = x_i^{2a+b}
\quad\text{ for each }\;i = 1, \ldots, n
$$
As a result,

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (a x_i^2 + b x_i + c) \ge \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{2a+b} = \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{2a+b} = 1^{2a+b} = 1$$